# Android Labels or Bubbles in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]Can someone please point me in the right direction how to do those bubbles or labels in the EditText something like those you see when you want to compose something in Stream for Google+ when you add a circle or contact? The Rectangle is an auto complete edittext.

Comment: Dear put the possible snapshot whenever you talk about and give example of any other application so that we can catch exactly. I hope you got my point. 1 snap = 10000 words :)

Comment: They used to restrict images. >.< Don't know why it's uploading 2 pics either

Comment: +1 Anyway nice question.

Comment: Are "Your circles" and "Extended circles" different EditText?

Comment: Only 1 EditText with 2 bubbles in it.

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext

Answer (score 18):

What you are showing is the same behavior as the SMS stock application. Search for the code [here](https://github.com/android) to see how it's done.

EDIT:

The code should be in [platform_packages_apps_mms](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms). Take a look at the [RecipientsEditor](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java) class.

Comment: @David: Check the sms application when you create a new sms. You will be able to pick between more than one. The sms code is open source.

Comment: This was a pretty good link that lead me to read up on the MultiAutoCompleteTextView which kinda showed how the autocomplete portion works. The code describes that it is delimited by a "," or ";" but the above shows no delimiter and an image. The cool thing is when u press backspace on the "bubble" it deletes the whole word! Does the text have a background image in it or did I miss something?

Comment: @Maurice: I would guess that's a `TextView` with a gray `android:background` and an `android:leftDrawable`

Comment: From what I can tell, you need to use the `Spannable` system (which I describe in another answer) to get drawables into a `TextView`/`EditText` that flow as text.

Comment: Works on 4+ devices but not on 2.3... (Not tested on any 3)

Comment: If anyone's interested, I've published a similar solution on GitHub: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ChipsLibrary .

Answer (score 8):

I built [TokenAutoComplete on github](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) to solve a similar problem and it should work for you as well. Here's a basic implementation of a demo app:

```
public class ContactsCompletionView extends TokenCompleteTextView {
    public ContactsCompletionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(Object object) {
        Person p = (Person)object;

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)l.inflate(R.layout.contact_token, (ViewGroup)ContactsCompletionView.this.getParent(), false);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getEmail());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object defaultObject(String completionText) {
        //Stupid simple example of guessing if we have an email or not
        int index = completionText.indexOf('@');
        if (index == -1) {
            return new Person(completionText, completionText.replace(" ", "") + "@example.com");
        } else {
            return new Person(completionText.substring(0, index), completionText);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout code for contact_token (you can use any kind of layout here or could throw an ImageView in if you want images in the token)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/token_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Token backgound drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ffafafaf" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Person object code

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Person(String n, String e) { name = n; email = e; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

Sample activity

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity {
    ContactsCompletionView completionView;
    Person[] people;
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        people = new Person[]{
                new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
                new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
                new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
                new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
                new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
                new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com")
        };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);

        completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey i am getting this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tokenautocomplete.TokenActivity"

Comment: @user1051505 check your main xml file

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating a subclass of [`android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan.html). [`ImageSpan`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) is an example of this: it replaces a span (range) of text with an image.

This example will put an a star in an edit field, replacing the text "test". Create an EditText in your layout with the id of "text" and put this in `onCreate()` (or wherever):

```
    EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    final Editable e = mText.getEditableText();
    final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    sb.append("test");
    sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, android.R.drawable.btn_star), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    e.append(sb);
```

I didn't see any classes that looked like they could wrap normal text in a drawable, but that could be pretty easily solved by overriding the `getDrawable()` method and rendering the text yourself.

Comment: This was interesting. You are able to put the image in the edittext but you have to backspace 4 times to delete the whole image.

Comment: I suspect the "Your circles" in the above is "Your circles," in text but covered by an image as described in this answer. Now to figure out how to delete the whole text when you delete the delimiter....

Comment: The backspacing a few times actually depends on the Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE part of the span. Try playing around with a few different settings - there are 4 total.

Comment: As far as the "your circles" in text, you're probably right. You can also add extra information into the flow of your text using the `Annotation` class that was pointed to in Macarse's answer. I suspect the final answer would use both classes.

Comment: All 4 don't work, just tried it. I'm guessing it has something to do with a textwatcher.

Comment: Ah. Then it was probably an issue with where the span was. I made some revisions to the sample code in my answer, so perhaps you have an earlier revision. Make sure that the span ranges from 0 to 4. I'll post a complete set of working code in a moment.

Comment: Here's the class: http://staticfree.info/clip/2011-11-19T235307 and the layout http://staticfree.info/clip/2011-11-19T235336

Comment: Very cool. Now we just got to figure out how to display the text with a picture and integrate it with the MultiAutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: This ImageSpan looks like it replaces a span of text.  How do you create a custom background span, so that you can see the text on top, just like the Google+ app works?

Comment: try a 9-patch with a content area defined.

Comment: @StevePomeroy, how can you have multiple 9-patch images in an EditText view like the MultiAutoCompleteTextView?  also how would you convert text into a 9 patch image?

Comment: The idea is that you'd use a 9-patch for an ImageSpan background. I'm not sure if it'd work (I never was able to get text on top of an image like this question is asking without needing to draw the text myself)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this HERE [Contact Bubble EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext/10864568#10864568)

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
TextView tv = createContactTextView(contactName);
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(tv);
bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(),bd.getIntrinsicHeight());

sb.append(contactName + ",");
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length()-(contactName.length()+1),sb.length()-1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
to_input.setText(sb);

public static Object convertViewToDrawable(View view) {
  int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  view.measure(spec, spec);
  view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
  c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
  view.draw(c);
  view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap cacheBmp = view.getDrawingCache();
  Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
  view.destroyDrawingCache();
  return new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);

}

public TextView createContactTextView(String text){
  //creating textview dynamically
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText(text);
  tv.setTextSize(20);
  tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval);
  tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_clear_search_api_holo_light, 0);
  return tv;
}
```

Comment: the above image does not have any delimiter....is it possible to have an empty delimiter instead of using ","..I tried without giving any tokenizer but the multiautocompletetextview does not show any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the hints, you can add the simply with:

```
android:hint="@string/myHint"
```

This will put the grey label in the EditText when it is empty.

Comment: Not hints, it looks like an object in it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the circle icon in the left of the `EditText` you can change the `leftDrawable`.

You can do it on the layout xml file `android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon"` or programmatically using the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` function.

If you also want to give the bubble style, you must change the backgroud drawable by a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)   that have the style. [here](http://www.anddev.org/map-tutorials-f18/nice-bubble-in-android-maps-t52751.html) you have a tutorial for a 9-patch bubble for google maps.

Hope it helped! :)

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking. He has only one edit text, and the text entries can be styled. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I think it use setCompoundDrawables() method to insert that picture inside edit text

Comment: That was already suggested in Jordi's answer, but that kind of drawable doesn't flow with the text as the poster wants.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to give something back to the community and created library that is aimed to solve this exact problem You have. The library along with example project is availeable on GitHub: https://github.com/RafalManka/BubbleEditText