# Custom Spannable = ImageSpan + BackgroundColorSpan + ClickableSpan

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I would like to have a custom `Spannable` class which somehow combines the behaviour of `ImageSpan`, `BackgroundColorSpan` and `ClickableSpan`. So basically something like the [labels or bubbles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090711/android-labels-or-bubbles-in-edittext) plus a click handler. Or in other words: I need to place an icon in front of a word and draw a custom background behind that word. I dived through [`ReceipentEditor`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java) and [other classes](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/text/style) but couldn't find the ultimate hint yet.

I tried to accomblish this by extending `DynamicDrawableSpan` but this would replace the text and I don't want to bother drawing the text manually. What would be the best way to implement such a custom `Spannable`? Or is there a better way without using `Spannables`? Any tips or hints are appreciated!

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext

Comment: @toobsco42 this is pretty much what I want. You also got the same problem I have ;) From what I've seen so far, it looks like you need to render the text in order to overlay the background drawable.

Comment: how exactly do you render text to overlay the background drawable?

Comment: @toobsco42 I haven't done it so far. But I guess you would need to extend `BitmapDrawable` and overwrite `draw()`. There you have access to `Canvas.drawText()`. The tricky part might be to figure out the right font and text size.

Comment: I came across [this tutorial](http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-gosmsproevernote-like-edittext/) and it was exactly what I needed. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented something similar.  In my implementation, clicking on a bubble will delete it.  To do so, I just use ImageSpan for the TextView.  Then add an OnClickListener to the TextView.

Inside the OnClickListener, obtain the cursor position with getSelectionStart().  Determine which ImageSpan the position is associated with.  Rebuild and redraw the TextView without that ImageSpan entry.

Comment: I didn't think of this :-) Well, this could work out.
But actually it would be nicer to have a _componented_ Spannable which eleminates the need to do stuff in the overlaying TextView

Comment: How do you use an ImageSpan for the EditText view?  I tried like this:

final Editable e = tv.getEditableText();
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append(text);
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.background_span), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

However this the span of characters in "text" show up as invisible.  My background_span.xml is a shape drawable.

Comment: I am also Tried with Recipient Editor Class. But my problem is i am adding Extra Text if i have More chips in my edit text. So this count is repeating in higher end devices.. if i added +2 for extra 2 contatcs. it is coming +2+2 in higher end devices.. @radium22