# add our own UI to a view android xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have to add multiple options to an edit_text view as shown below, the views can be adjustable with the parent. I am not getting an idea how to do this, Can any one help how can we make this UI.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you must need to create custom edittext for this.

Comment: What behavior is this widget supposed to have?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at these `open source project` in `Github`

1. https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ
2. https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete
3. https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library

See the below `ScreenShots` for the **same**

**Hope this is what you are looking for.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you Amit, I am using [ChipsLibrary](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/chips-text-fields/). i have edited some code in the library to achieve the UI of the screen. As I am adding other stuff as chip data rather than contacts or mail-id's back functionality is not working properly. Means when we press back key entire chip is not deleting it's coming to edit mode.  How can I solve this? Can you plz help me... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are some SO posts which may meet your need.Refer the below posts,

[Creating a custom editText with tag-like feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318551/creating-a-custom-edittext-with-tag-like-feature)

[Contact Bubble EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext)