# Add multiple contacts in editText

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I write simple sms application and I try to implement adding multiple contacts. I tried to do with commas but it isn't intuitive. How can I add button with contact name to editText like is it in native sms application? Any idea?

Comment: have a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318551/creating-a-custom-edittext-with-tag-like-feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take layout for that. & inside layout you can put edittext & next to it button

For Example,

```
   <RelativeLayout>

         <Edittext>

         <Button>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

This is a simple sample case to implement above functionality. You need to mange design as per your requirement. & on button click you can add number of contacts in edittext setText() method separating by them ",".