# How to insert a custom view inline, inside an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is anyone knows how to insert `CardView`-like views into an `EditText` in **ANDROID** inline? I did google up for a bit, and just found the library that is specifically for browsing contacts like the one in gmail android app.

**I need to use it something like the tag `TextBox` in stackoverflow, when we are going to post / edit a question.**

1 pic worth a thousand words, so here we go:

**SNIP FROM SO** 
[image: Snip taken from stackoverflow.com]

**SNIP FROM GMAIL ANDROID APP**
[image: Snip taken from gmail android app]

Maybe something like `Chips` like [this](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html). I have no problem of creating such `View` myself, the problem is to insert it into an `EditText`. Thank you.

P.S. My min sdk version is 19

**UPDATE:** Just saw how this is handled in SO android app. I think it's not bad tho, but still, I prefer inline solution if able.[image]

Comment: I think this thread has some good answers for what you're looking for :
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext)

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318551/creating-a-custom-edittext-with-tag-like-feature)