# tags add in EditText Field Dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

how can I add dynamically multiple text boxes like this into the editText field. If anyone knows please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a custom editText with tag-like feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318551/creating-a-custom-edittext-with-tag-like-feature)

Comment: you can create custom tagview using **flexbox-layout**  https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout and recyclerview

Answer (score 3):

> Check out these links there , there are several lib available on Git

[AndroidTagView](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView)

[TagView](https://github.com/Cutta/TagView)

[TagsEditText](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText)

Comment: but brother this is editable text field. I can also add more text using keyboard in upper field where text boxes are adding.

Comment: I will implement it then i will tell you.