# how to add text with format into edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

The image is from an app called `kakao story`.

Suppose there's a post with a list of comments like any sns apps.
When you click a comment, it inserts the user name of the commenter in the edit-text to indicate `my new comment is a reply to the user`.
(You can't add the same name more than once.)
When you hit backspace to delete the name, the entire characters that make up the name(e.g., chabeau in the example) will be deleted by 1-backspace.

I'm trying to mimic the behavior and want some pointers how to implement it or what to search for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Answer (score 2):

If you are in search of **bubble view**. You can achieve it by creating a subclass of  `android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan.ImageSpan` which will convert a portion of `EditText` string into formatted `span`.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext/10864568#10864568) will give you some basic idea about creating formatted span.

[This](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/customizing-the-android-edittext-behavior-with-spans/) is a good tutorial for customizing `editext` with `spans`.

And for deleting whole word at once, you can use [SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE) property.

Below code will format the first four character of the string, Hope this will give you some hint.

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("your text here");
final ForegroundColorSpan fcs
    = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

// Span to set text color to some RGB value
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 

yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
et.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("yourColorCodeHere"));
```