# Set predefined values to MultiAutoCompleteTextView : Android

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-widget, custom-controls

I have to set some predefined values to `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` (before I select from suggestion drop down list). It's like, as if you selected 2-3 items from drop-down list. After setting these predefined values, again I want to continue with normal process of filtering from the list and add it to `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

It would look like this

```
Predefined1, Predefined2, Predefined3,
```

If I do setText(...) as you do with `TextView` or `EditText`, with some comma separated values, its considering it as 1 whole word and adding a comma at the end.

Please suggest how can I implement it.

**Edit :**

Okay. Let me explain in detail. I am trying to achieve like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext/10864568#10864568) and [this](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Spannable). But, 1 extra requirement from this is that, along with selecting value from suggestion drop down, I also need to set some predefined values when View is displayed and when I write something and press enter/hide keyboard, whatever i wrote should be converted into button text.
If it's not possible, any other alternative? Please suggest.

**Edit :**

[image]

These values should be there in view without selecting from drop down. Later, whichever users add from suggestion drop down, those also should be added to list.

**It's like setting hint or some text to `EditText`** before user starts typing.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't make my 50 reputation go waste consecutively for 2nd time :(

Comment: So, to make sure I understand correctly, you need the drop down Auto complete List view to be initialized with certain values and any other value the user types to be added as well?

Comment: Along with this, those predefined values need to be in MultiAutoCompleteTextView when initialized. Attached a sample image. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
   ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("Predefined1");
    data.add("Predefined2");
    data.add("Predefined3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data.toArray());
             MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(/*View id*/);

MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer tokenizer=new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer();

             textView.setAdapter(adapter);
             textView.setTokenizer(tokenizer);

    textView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
     @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                data.add(v.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

textView.setText("Predefined1,");
tokenizer.terminateToken("Predefined1");


textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"Predefined2,");
tokenizer.terminateToken("Predefined2");

textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"Predefined3,");
tokenizer.terminateToken("Predefined3");
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Try the modified code.

Comment: Edited solution worked!. Its been a long time i struck in this. Thanks a lot. Some modification are there. I will take care of them. Here u take bounty :)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, setting text is working fine. I have 1 more issue. As in that link, wrapping that text with border n cross button is not working while adding predefined text. If u could hv a look, it would b very helpful for me

Comment: how to add the clicklistener to the (x) image in the textview to delete the text.