# How to add the images into the edit text field and how to save it as the whole edit text image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button, android-imagebutton

In my app I am going to appear one screen,In that screen I am going to put the edit text field and below that edit text field I will use pick and save buttons,inside the edit text field I am going to type some text and after that where the cursor is pointing in that place I have to add the images, I would like to be taken images from the gallery using pick button and after put the images into the edit text field again I want to type some thing after that I am going to click the save button that edit text field saved as a images into the gallery are some thing else I have searched in Google regarding this but I can not able to find any solutions please any one would help me.

[image: The below image i want to save as image view and i need to add the image into the edit text field again where the cursor pointing in the place i have to pick the image from gallery]

Comment: That is known as chips or bubble kind edit text. You can get some idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext or http://www.kpbird.com/2013/02/android-chips-edittext-token-edittext.html, and if your app's minimumsdk level is 14 then try https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ

Comment: I have used the layout for the edit text field i need the java code to  pick and save the images files.

Comment: where do you want the image save to?

Comment: I want to save the whole edit text field as Image into the gallery or SD card,Before that how do i pick the images into the edit text field as i given link  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/USlnQ.png

Comment: Updated reply in answer. Let me know if u still face problem.

Comment: You gave one link know, It is running but it showing only the edit text fields alone how can i get the images into the edit text.

Answer (score 1):

EditText is a one type of View. Convert that view into bitmap and store them where ever you want. And Java code for that is

```
// capture bitmapt of genreated textview
int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
textView.measure(spec, spec);
textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(), textView.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());
textView.draw(canvas);
textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
textView.destroyDrawingCache(); // destory drawable
```

Find full example in this class https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library/blob/master/ChipsEditTextLibrary/src/com/kpbird/chipsedittextlibrary/ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.java

Set image in EditText

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
    BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
    bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0,bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    // create and set imagespan
    ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable),x ,x + c.length() , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
edtText.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: Before that i need to take the image from the gallery to the edit text if there is any possible.

Comment: Updated my answer. Also please have a look at the link. Code for both(Image to text and text to image) is available there.

Comment: sorry Hardik Trivedi, this code is not help full for me, I want to pick the images from the gallery.

Comment: To pick image from gallery use intents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Comment: inside the edit text field how can i get the images from the gallery, weather i want to use image view inside the image view.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/USlnQ.png                              You can see this link I will take the images like this only to edit text from the gallery, I got sample code for this but they pick the image from the drawable, but I want to pick from gallery would you help me pls.

Comment: Buddy I am trying to explain you the same thing. Did u give a try to above code. there one image is appeded after text, you need to modify above logic for 3 images as you have shown in your reference image. And convert images to bitmap whatever you are getting from gallery.

Comment: Buddy no 3 images, first initially we type something in then the cursor is pointing, on that time we click the gallery button and choose one image and add into the edit text fields, then we will type something again we click the gallery again import any image into the edit fields .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54486/discussion-between-hardik-trivedi-and-manoj).

Comment: I got a error on this line for null pointer exception                                ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable),x ,x + c.length() , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable),x ,x + c.length() , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);                                      I got an error on this line