# Android Multi-AutoComplete-TextView with different text bubbles (chips) in it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

[image]

how to create android Multi Auto-Complete Text-View with chips

Comment: I think you must go with custom layout

Comment: can you tell me what this feature called ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext

Comment: they are called chips in android https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Comment: check this library -https://github.com/OfficialAmal/ChipLayout

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple library for this purpose : https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView

Here a quickstart :

Add ChipView to your layout or create it programmatically :

```
<com.plumillonforge.android.chipview.ChipView
    android:id="@+id/chipview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Init it with a list of data which extend Chip interface and add a click listener (if you want) :

```
List<Chip> chipList = new ArrayList<>();
chipList.add(new Tag("Lorem"));
chipList.add(new Tag("Ipsum dolor"));
chipList.add(new Tag("Sit amet"));
chipList.add(new Tag("Consectetur"));
chipList.add(new Tag("adipiscing elit"));
ChipView chipDefault = (ChipView) findViewById(R.id.chipview);
chipDefault.setChipList(chipList);
chipDefault.setOnChipClickListener(new OnChipClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChipClick(Chip chip) {
            // Action here !
        }
    });
```

Default ChipView is rendered like this :

[image: Default ChipView]

But you can customise as you like from overall to Chip level :

[image: Overall ChipView]
[image: Custom ChipView]

This isn't a MultiAutocomplete but you can manage to mimic it (I'm actually using it like that)

Comment: Could you expand this answer to show some code and the output using your library?

Comment: Plumillon Forge, Is there a way to make a chipview horizontally scrollable? In the sense that it only takes a single line, not multiple lines.

Comment: @code.mi There is not at the moment, I have to do it since you're not the only one asking

Comment: That would be awesome, as you would be the first to implement this kind of layout. Thanks a million for your contribution.

Comment: @PlumillonForge how to disable a chipview

Comment: @PlumillonForge, I have been following your documentation on GitHub, and have implemented the chipView in my code. However, I don't know where to start with merging this with or mimicing MultiAutocomplete. Do you have any pointers to get me started?

Comment: @ChristopherMills ChipView is extending ViewGroup (you can't type in there) so I think you will have to play a little with the code. Maybe you can do a little trick with an Autocomplete view next to the ChipView ?

Answer (score 1):

Material Design specifications include something called [chips](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips.html), which do what you are asking for. A library is found [here](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips).