# EditText filter whole words

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is the scenario.

I have an EditText. This EditText should be able to limit text input to a set of certain words (a custom "dictionary"). 
Words may be added by clicking the respective button (no keyboard input!).

Words in the EditText can be deleted by positioning the cursor behind a word and hitting a "backspace button". On a delete action, the whole word should be deleted (instead of a single character).

Cursor positioning in between characters of a word shouldn't be possible.

Example:

Button 1: "Car"
Button 2: "drives" 
Button 3: "slowly"

Clicking Button 1,2,3 adds the respective word to the EditText.

Content EditText: "Car drives slowly"

Positioning of cursor only able before or after every word. Deletion of word only possible as a whole.

Is that possible at all? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is something Related with Tags Concept.

Have a look at [Contact Bubble EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext)