# Android : Stack Overflow Like Tag Input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to create an EditView in Android similar to how tag input system works on Stack Overflow when you have to specify tags for input ie as soon as you enter spacebar (comma) in my case the entered text is styled ie similar to the way Stack Overflow tags appear. I am newbie to android and Java and would appreciate any directions/help/code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that what I wanted to do was already asked and answered by stackoveflow community before. You can find the answer at 
[Contact Bubble EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext/10864568#10864568) as well at [Android Labels or Bubbles in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090711/android-labels-or-bubbles-in-edittext)

Answer (score 3):

Add a horizontal linear layout in a horizontal scrollview in your layout.
Register Text Watcher with your EditText and monitor input.
in the override method onTextchanged() check whether the entered character is space or comma add button in horizontal linear layout and give previous word before space or comma as the button text.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I already got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext/10864568#10864568