# Chips widget in Android application

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I would like to use chips widget functionality like we enter the email address in Android phones in Gmail app. I found one good library [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/android-cts-4.1_r2/chips/src/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java).
But don't know how to use it with my Android application, has anyone tried this lib?

Also in my case I have a screen with listview and edittext, when we type in edittext it will show the filtered result from list in overlay. and on selecting the result. It will listed in editext as a chip.

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are the useful link:--

1. http://www.kpbird.com/2013/02/android-chips-edittext-token-edittext.html
2. [Android EditText Gmail like to field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747809/android-edittext-gmail-like-to-field)
3. [Android Labels or Bubbles in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090711/android-labels-or-bubbles-in-edittext/8128848#8128848)
4. [Contact Bubble EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext)

enjoy..!

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/platform-features-talk-io-2013/source/browse/src/com/example/iotalk/ChipsActivity.java has a very simple example, once you've imported the library from frameworks/ex/chips

Comment: your code does not work out of the box and seems to require api-16