# How do I bind contact cursor data to a MultiAutoCompleteTextView with chips

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contacts, autocompletetextview

I have been at this for almost two weeks now. I believe I have come close, but I can't quite get the final product to work. I have a functionality similar to email in my app. But instead of email addresses, it uses phone numbers. The gmail app on android is able to use a MultiAutoCompleteTextView **with chips** to display recipient email addresses. That is what I want to do. Through my research and trials, I am able to create the MultiAutoCompleteTextView, but without the chips. There are a number of questions and answers here on the same subject. But invariably, none of the ones I find has an example that binds the data from a user's contact book to the MultiAutoCompleteTextView. All the examples I see use their own made up simple arrays, as if the final step were trivial. But the final step is where I am stuck. Each time I try to bind the contact book to an MultiAutoCompleteTextView with chips, the code fails. So my question is quite extremely specific: **How do I bind the contact book to an MultiAutoCompleteTextView with chips?** For some context, I have already read [Chips widget in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873245/chips-widget-in-android-application) and bunch of other articles and responses besides. Is anyone aware of my specific use case? The gmail use case?

**EDIT**

Following is the code I use with https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete . But the `getView` of my adapter is never called.

**code to bind adapter to editText**

```
mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), mPeopleList, R.layout.contacts_row);
multiEdit = (ContactsAutoCompleteView) view.findViewById(R.id.multi_edit);
multiEdit.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**code to load contact book**

```
public void PopulatePeopleList() {

    mPeopleList.clear();

    Cursor people = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);

    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

        if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0) {

            // You know have the number so now query it like this
            Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                // store numbers and display a dialog letting the user select which.
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                if (numberType.equals("0")) {
                    numberType = "Work";
                } else if (numberType.equals("1")) {
                    numberType = "Home";
                } else if (numberType.equals("2")) {
                    numberType = "Mobile";
                } else {
                    numberType = "Other";
                }
                mPeopleList.add(new Contact(contactName, phoneNumber, numberType));
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();

    getActivity().startManagingCursor(people);
}
```

**my adapter**

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final int mRowResourceId;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<Contact> mContacts;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts, int contactsRow) {
        super(context, contactsRow, contacts);
        mContext = context;
        mRowResourceId = contactsRow;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        if (null == rowView) {
            rowView = mInflater.inflate(mRowResourceId, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewsHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewsHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            viewsHolder.phone = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
            viewsHolder.type = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_type);
            rowView.setTag(viewsHolder);
        }
        ViewHolder viewsHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        Contact con = mContacts.get(position);// getItem(position);
        viewsHolder.name.setText(con.getName());
        viewsHolder.phone.setText(con.getPhone());
        viewsHolder.type.setText(con.getType());
        return rowView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView phone;
        TextView type;
    }

}
```

**my contact object: accessors and constructor not shown**

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String type;
}
```

**My TokenCompleteTextView: ?? what goes inside defaultObject**

```
public class ContactsAutoCompleteView extends TokenCompleteTextView {

public ContactsAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected View getViewForObject(Object object) {
    Contact p = (Contact) object;

    LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) l.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row,
            (ViewGroup) ContactsAutoCompleteView.this.getParent(), false);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name)).setText(p.getName());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone)).setText(p.getPhone());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_type)).setText(p.getType());

    return view;
}

@Override
protected Object defaultObject(String completionText) {
    //what goes here?
}

@Override
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    super.setSelected(selected);

}
```

}

Comment: when I try to use the chips, when I type in the textview nothing happens, no suggestions. Then I run the code in debug mode to find that the adapter is never accessed.

Comment: if your data model is a Cursor why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @pskink that is what I had before finding a `chip` library. The chip library I am showing requires a Contact object not a `Map<String,String>

Comment: i already posted a similar solution with searching for names or phone numbers, so whats so hard to add email functionality? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443791/multiautocompletetextview-with-contacts-phone-numbers

Comment: @pskink yes, I remember your help along the way. But the `chips` are very important. Gmail uses the chips. The problem is when I try to include the chips that the code fails.

Comment: chips are no problem to implement, as easy as implementing two one-liner methods

Comment: and the whole thing is 70 lines of code only :)

Answer (score 0):

Few weeks ago i was in your situation, and what I did was to use a library for the chips

I used [this one](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

as for the bind with the contacts be more specific where are you stuck and what are you get ?

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at your link. But as I explain above, when I try to use a chip library, my adapter's `getview` method is never called.

Comment: Actually I just looked at your library. I have tried it. I will edit my answer to show my code that fails with it. But basically I extend ArrayAdapter and pass that to the textview.

Comment: I have edited to show my complete code. Since you have solved this same problem, you may be my hope. Thanks. You may edit your response with the appropriate feedback/hints. thanks.

Comment: also what is your implementation of `defaultObject`? I understand my POJO is more complex than the one in the sample code.

Comment: my Implementation for defaultObject was not supporting and return empty contact

Comment: I am showing my entire code, can you spot any mistakes?