# RecyclerView with editTags

Tags: android, search, tags, android-recyclerview

[image: My output coming like this]I am doing one application. In that i need to search the recycler item and once the user selects item from recycler then it should be set as a tag to that edit text.  I did this from this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3581, but its not working properly. Can any help me how can i achieve the searching the items from recycler view and set it as a edit tag for that selected item.[image]

This is the screen for reference.

I am doing like this

```
public class ActivityTagFriends extends BaseActivity  implements TagsEditText.TagsEditListener, View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tv_cancel, tv_title, tv_Done;
    RecyclerView rv_TagFriends;
    private TagsEditText mTagsEditText;

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    TagFriendsAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag_friends);

        tv_cancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);
        tv_cancel.setText("Cancel");
        tv_cancel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tv_title.setText("Tag Friends");
        tv_title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        tv_Done = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDone);
        tv_Done.setText("Done");
        tv_Done.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        rv_TagFriends= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_TagFriends);
        mTagsEditText = (TagsEditText) findViewById(R.id.tagsEditText);
        mTagsEditText.setHint("Search");
        mTagsEditText.setTagsListener(this);
        mTagsEditText.setTagsWithSpacesEnabled(true);
       mTagsEditText.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
               R.layout.tag_friends_row, R.id.tv_TagName,list));
        mTagsEditText.setThreshold(1);

        rv_TagFriends.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv_TagFriends.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        countryList();  // in this method, Create a list of items.

        // call the adapter with argument list of items and context.
      //  mAdapter = new TagFriendsAdapter(list,this);
       // rv_TagFriends.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        addTextListener();


    }

    // this method is used to create list of items.
    public void countryList(){

        list.add("Afghanistan");
        list.add("Albania");
        list.add("Algeria");
        list.add("Bangladesh");
        list.add("Belarus");
        list.add("Canada");
        list.add("Cape Verde");
        list.add("Central African Republic");
        list.add("Denmark");
        list.add("Dominican Republic");
        list.add("Egypt");
        list.add("France");
        list.add("Germany");
        list.add("Hong Kong");
        list.add("India");
        list.add("Iceland");

    }



    public void addTextListener(){

        mTagsEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

                query = query.toString().toLowerCase();

                final List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = list.get(i).toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(query)) {

                        filteredList.add(list.get(i));

                    }
                }

                rv_TagFriends.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityTagFriends.this));
                mAdapter = new TagFriendsAdapter(filteredList, ActivityTagFriends.this);

                rv_TagFriends.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              // data set changed
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
          //  mTagsEditText.showDropDown();

              // data set changed
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTagsChanged(Collection<String> tags) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEditingFinished() {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Labels or Bubbles in EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090711/android-labels-or-bubbles-in-edittext)

Comment: i tried this my my implementation is different. If i am searching in editext and if i selected recycler item , then that tags should set to edittext and tag shoild apply for that item

Comment: There are edittext libraries available to achieve tags, use that and implement `Filterable` in your recyclerView adapter class and on search call the filter method. Add onclick listener for the recyclerview item and `onClick` set that text as the tag in edittext. It is that simple

Comment: roundI edited my question, please check.. I am doing like that... but i am facing problem for setting the adapter selected value to the tag background

Comment: You should not set the adapter every time when user enters a char. Instead create adapter and set it to recyclerView initially. Implement `Filterable` interface in the adapter and on textChangedListener, call `mAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchString);`. Check this [example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/05/13/filtering-a-recyclerview-with-custom-objects/) for implementing filterable interface in adapter.

Comment: i dont have issue with selecting, filtering. I am not able to set the recycler item to the tagview..

Comment: Where is your item click listener? Do it there

Comment: its in the adapter class and the thing is I am using  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3581 to set the tag, so my out put come in 2 different forms because this link its populating spinner and I am setting recycler view. So its showing 2 different ways

Comment: I added My output screen. Please check it once

Comment: Then check if you can disable the popup which is shown by edittext. If you can't disable the popup, then you have to find some other library or implement your own.

Comment: i think so we cannot disable that spinner. And i  didnt get any library related to my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got your problem use this code

**Your activity layout(activity_main.xml)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:TagsEditText="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context="mabbas007.myapplication.MainActivity">

  <mabbas007.tagsedittext.TagsEditText
  android:id="@+id/tagsEditText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  TagsEditText:allowSpaceInTag="true"
  TagsEditText:tagsBackground="@drawable/square_default"
  TagsEditText:tagsCloseImageRight="@drawable/tag_close" />

  <TextView
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Suggestion"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/rv"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

**adapter layout(adapter_item.xml)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/colorAccent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  implements TagsEditText.TagsEditListener {

 RecyclerView rv_TagFriends;
  private TagsEditText mTagsEditText;

  private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  TagFriendsAdapter mAdapter;
  ArrayList<String > tags;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  tags=new ArrayList<>();
  rv_TagFriends= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
  mTagsEditText = (TagsEditText) findViewById(R.id.tagsEditText);
  mTagsEditText.setHint("Search");
  mTagsEditText.setTagsListener(this);
  mTagsEditText.setTagsWithSpacesEnabled(true);
  //mTagsEditText.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  mTagsEditText.setThreshold(1);

  rv_TagFriends.setHasFixedSize(true);
  rv_TagFriends.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


  countryList(); // in this method, Create a list of items.

  // call the adapter with argument list of items and context.
  // mAdapter = new TagFriendsAdapter(list,this);
  // rv_TagFriends.setAdapter(mAdapter);

  addTextListener();


  }

  // this method is used to create list of items.
  public void countryList(){

  list.add("Afghanistan");
  list.add("Albania");
  list.add("Algeria");
  list.add("Bangladesh");
  list.add("Belarus");
  list.add("Canada");
  list.add("Cape Verde");
  list.add("Central African Republic");
  list.add("Denmark");
  list.add("Dominican Republic");
  list.add("Egypt");
  list.add("France");
  list.add("Germany");
  list.add("Hong Kong");
  list.add("India");
  list.add("Iceland");

  }



  public void addTextListener(){

  mTagsEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

  query = query.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
  if (query.toString().equals(""))
  return;
  if (tags.size()!=0)
  query=query.toString().substring(query.toString().indexOf(tags.get(tags.size()-1).toLowerCase())+tags.get(tags.size()-1).toString().length()).trim();
  if (query.toString().equals("")){
  final List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
  rv_TagFriends.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
  mAdapter = new TagFriendsAdapter(filteredList, MainActivity.this);
  rv_TagFriends.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }else {
  final List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  final String text = list.get(i).toLowerCase();
  if (text.contains(query)) {
  filteredList.add(list.get(i));
  }
  }

  rv_TagFriends.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
  mAdapter = new TagFriendsAdapter(filteredList, MainActivity.this);
  rv_TagFriends.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }


  }
  });


  }







  @Override
  public void onTagsChanged(Collection<String> tags) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onEditingFinished() {

  }


  public class TagFriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

  private List<String > data;
  private MainActivity mainActivity;

  public TagFriendsAdapter(List<String> data , MainActivity mainActivity) {
  this.data = data;
  this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_item, parent, false));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  ((MyViewHolder)holder).text.setText(data.get(position)+"");
  ((MyViewHolder)holder).text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  mainActivity.add(data.get(position)+"");
  }
  });
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
  return data.size();
  }

  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView text;
  public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
  super(itemView);
  text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
  }
  }
  }



  public void add(String s){
  for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
  if (s.equals(tags.get(i)))
  return;
  }
  tags.add(s);
  String [] tag=tags.toArray(new String [0]);
  mTagsEditText.setTags(tag);
  }

  }
```

Comment: Copy exactly this code or still problem exist then share your code.

Comment: yeah still I am getting Index bound Exception sometimes

Comment: Okay Sure. Thank you. And if I enter some thing like ppp and if i use enter key from soft keyboard its accepting that value and setting the tag